# Как сделать кнопки + и - для edit?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть вот такая структура формы, содержит поле edit и по бокам кнопки плюс и минус:

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="pole">
    <span class="minus">
<button type="button"></button>
</span>
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <span class="plus">
<button type="button"></button>
</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Нужно чтобы по клике на кнопку + прибавлялось значение на 1, при минус - наоборот. Как это сделать?

Comment: Как это сделать: Написать обработчик нажатия на кнопки, чтобы при нажатии, бралось содержимое инпута, прибавляло (удаляло) 1, и записывало назад в инпут.

Comment: Эх, а как это сделать? Можете подсказать, пожалуйста? Или может есть пример?

Answer (score 2):

Решение "в лоб":

```js
function change(delta) {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + delta;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change(-1);">-</button>
<input id="input" type="text" value ="1" />
<button onclick="change(1);">+</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#minus').click(function(){
    var k = parseFloat($('#znach').val());
    if(k>1){
    k = k-1;
      }
    $('#znach').val(k);
    });
  
  $('#plus').click(function(){
    var k = parseFloat($('#znach').val());
    k = k+1;
    $('#znach').val(k);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="pole">
    <span class="minus">
<button type="button" id="minus">-</button>
</span>
    <input type="text" value="1" id="znach">
    <span class="plus">
<button type="button" id="plus">+</button>
</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать так, чтобы значения не уходили в минус и минимум оставалась 1?

Comment: @Александр а немного самому подумать и дописать в обработчик один if ?